# Google Sheets "Editor" permissions

Tags: google-sheets, permissions

Google Sheets "EDITOR", (1 person) cannot edit any cells. Other EDITORs (2 people) can. Please help. Not sure where to go to be able to allow this one EDITOR to edit an individual cell. Two other persons have the same EDITOR status and ARE able to edit cells.

Have recent invitation the user to see if this would open up permission to edit the cells. It did not. Have looked at settings, but see nothing about individual permissions to be granted.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the current issue in your script and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: In our spreadsheet we have 4 people authorized as EDITORs that can change, delete and add content to the individual cells on the page. One of the EDITORs cannot delete, add, or modify any individual cell on the page, the other 3 can. would like to know how to allow access or permission for the person to delete, add or modify content in those cells.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if protected ranges are present in this sheet (Data/Protected sheets and ranges)? This is a separate setting to access permissions.